# What is the origin of the term 'going to wrack and ruin'?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

'Wrack' refers to wreckage, vengeance and retributive punishment. From looking at its copious entry in the OED it is clear that the word 'wrack' has had a considerable history. But other than for this expression it seems to have disappeared from use. Is anyone able to contradict this?

Comment: According to Ngrams usage peaked in the early 1940s. However, bear in mind that _wrack_ is also a word for a kind of sea-weed, e.g bladderwrack.

Comment: It was fun. I'm sorry to have contradicted you. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*Rack* is a variant of the now defunct word wrack, more usually known to us now as wreck." [source](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/rack-and-ruin.html) 
*Wrack* (as *wreck*) was used as early as [1548](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/rack-and-ruin.html), in a sermon by Ephraim Udall:

> "The flocke goeth to wrecke and vtterly perisheth."
>   Henry Bull moved the phrase on to 'wrack and ruin' in his translation of Luther's Commentarie upon the fiftene psalmes, 1577:
>
> "Whiles all things seeme to fall to wracke and ruine."

However

> "The noun wrack means ruin or destruction, and generally is **confined to the phrase wrack and ruin and wracked with doubt (or pain)**. The verb wrack has substantially the same meaning as the verb rack, the latter being preferred."
>   (The Associated Press Stylebook and Briefing on Media Law 2011. Associated Press, 2011)

"Penny was wracked with sorrow for his friends." (Marjorie Kinnan Rawlings)

"It is early afternoon; a mother prepares her warrior son's torn body for burial. His father is wracked with sorrow, he is going through his belongings..." Angelika Bammer ([1994](http://books.google.com/books?id=4fZlIHY8ZWMC&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=%22wracked+with+sorrow%22&source=bl&ots=kothdhz3Tc&sig=wvuEbLTKfH07QkX-fOWSDn7-YUg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uGfqUov6HMjlsAS5gILQDA&ved=0CEEQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22wracked%20with%20sorrow%22&f=false))

"Again and again, the woman would return to the last painful moments until she was once more wracked with sorrow." Thomas Goodrich ([2005](http://books.google.com/books?id=AJJ-E9Z5qjIC&pg=PA185&lpg=PA185&dq=%22wracked+with+sorrow%22&source=bl&ots=kuA1wtgozo&sig=n7WCVlOsOEiWdEBmIo4PbRudrBM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uGfqUov6HMjlsAS5gILQDA&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22wracked%20with%20sorrow%22&f=false))

"So when the psalmist cannot connect with God, and when the psalmist is wracked with doubt about God's gracious presence in his life, what then?" John D. Suk ([2011](http://books.google.com/books?id=PUETL1hK6CIC&pg=PA135&lpg=PA135&dq=%22wracked+with+doubt%22&source=bl&ots=stGnQ1gUaU&sig=n_kkTwE61XOKdxkoG6sXhiLfSpo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3GjqUunjDKTjsATP7oHwBA&ved=0CHYQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22wracked%20with%20doubt%22&f=false))

Comment: The OED says the phrase is *rack and ruin*, where *rack* has an unusual sense of 'neglect or disrepair'.

Comment: @TimLymington - yes, I know that. But the OED is not the law, and multiple other sources derive differently.

Comment: @Tim: The OED says that *rack* in *rack and ruin* is etymologically an alternate spelling of *wrack*, and not the usual meaning of *rack*. The OED also lists the phrase under *wrack and ruin*.